# What is the "Kzinti Lesson" from Larry Niven's Ringworld?

Tags: larry-niven, known-space, ringworld

I am re-reading *Ringworld* now, and I came across this term; does anyone know where I can find the origin in Niven's canon of work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> A reaction drive is a weapon effective in proportion to it's efficiency.

The in-universe origin can be traced back to the first contact between Humans and Kzin where

> the drive on the *Angel's Pencil* (a laser propelled slowboat) is used to destroy a Kzinti warship despite the Kzinti telepath's assessment that the Humans have "no weapons".

(told in "The Warriors") and the [subsequent Kzinti attempts to invade the solar system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Kzin_Wars#First_Man-Kzin_War).

Just now I'm not positive about where the phrase first appeared in text, but the *Ringworld* mention has to be close to the first.

Comment: According to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Kzin_Wars#The_stories) it first appeared in *If* magazine in 1966. It's probably easiest to find in **The Man-Kzin Wars** (the first book of short stories).

Comment: @MarthaF. I presume that "it" is "The Warriors"? An oddity of copyright law results in the collection not giving that data, but by concern was when the phrase "the Kzinti lesson" first appears.

Comment: While the Kzinti Lesson isn't mentioned by name (or even paraphrased) in "The Warriors", it shows up in the 1970 novel *Ringworld*: "A reaction drive is a weapon, powerful in direct ratio to its efficiency." (p.87, first ed. HC, 1977) However, I wouldn't be at all surprised if it were mentioned in the Beowulf Schaeffer stories since the character was prone to chattiness about factoids like this. (1966-1967, 1975)

Comment: @neilfein: Yes...Bey's ship in "Neutron Star" (1966) might bring it up, and then there is "The Ethics of Madness" (1967), but I can't recall anything before *Ringworld* with certainty.

Comment: Warning: Do not click on this TV Tropes link. [Weaponized Exhaust](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WeaponizedExhaust)

Comment: @neilfein Just noticed (years late) that you quoted the 1st edition. Does that mean you have one with Bey traveling the wrong direction to stay ahead of midnight? You lucky dog.

Comment: @dmckee - No, I think it's the 1970 1st edition paperback that has the errors. The 1st edition hardcover was printed in 1977.

Comment: I don't see how essentially any species capable of space flight, let alone interstellar space flight, could not realize this.

Comment: @Adamant The set-up relies on two things. Firstly that the Kzin use reactionless drives for all stages of space-flight (so no practical experience with mitiigating the risks of drive reaction plumes) and secondly that their telepaths assure them that these prey are disarmed by choice.

Comment: Forget about exhaust, the whole spaceship is a potential weapon if going that fast, however it gets up to that speed.

Comment: @dmckee I assume you meant to say Louis goes the wrong way in the 1st edition of *Ringworld*. ;)