# Identify a sci-fi painting of a man in a space suit flying just above a horde of aliens

Tags: object-identification

I remember a painting in a book from when I was a child. I think it was an anthology or encyclopaedia of sci-fi or something like that, and it was very large. There were several paintings in the book, but the one that really stood out was of a man in a space suit with some kind of propulsion mechanism. He seemed to be struggling to stay just out of reach of aliens on the ground, who were reaching up to grab his feet.

Can anyone identify the image or the book?

Comment: When were you a child?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something [like this](http://www.peterelson.co.uk/gallery/image.php?cat=10&id=312) painting by Peter Elson?

I'm pretty sure it was reprinted in one of the *Terran Trade Authority* books.

[image]

Comment: Looks like Harry Harrison used it as a cover for Prime Number (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3616135-prime-number) but that wouldn't match for there being multiple pictures in the book.

Comment: @SeanDuggan see my edit above, it was possibly included in a *Terran Trade Authority* book.

Comment: Not shown in the picture: the aliens below scattered and [burning up in the heat of the jet pack exhaust.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13044/what-is-the-kzinti-lesson-from-larry-nivens-ringworld) Even if the exhaust is cold (and it sure doesn't *look* cold in the picture), it should still feel like a firehose to the face at that range. With hot rocket exhaust, it should be more like a gas torch to the face. I'm not sure why he's even bothering with that dinky-looking little ray gun.

Comment: Thanks, I think that could be it. I remember something slightly different, with the guy a bit lower and coming from the right, buy it could just have been flipped. Thanks a lot, really.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Colonial racism and/or Terran supremacism, perhaps? *Pew, pew!*